# Using a argument as a property key

Tags: javascript

Lets say I got this function:

```
  vm.setSelectedItem = function(itemName, searchedItems){
    vm.selectedItem = _.findWhere(searchedItems, {name: itemName});
  };
```

I need to make the "name" dynamic

```
  vm.setSelectedItem = function(itemName, searchedItems, propertyKey){
    vm.selectedItem = _.findWhere(searchedItems, {}); //How do I use the arg propertyKey here?
  };
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vm.setSelectedItem = function(itemName, searchedItems, propertyKey)
{
    var obj = {};
    obj[ propertyKey ] = itemName;

    vm.selectedItem = _.findWhere(searchedItems, obj); //How do I use the arg propertyKey here?
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
  vm.setSelectedItem = function(itemName, searchedItems, propertyKey){
    var obj = {};
    obj[propertyKey] = itemName;
    vm.selectedItem = _.findWhere(searchedItems, obj);
  };
```

Comment: or, in ES6: `var obj = { [propertyKey]: itemName }`

Comment: with due respect, isn't this identical to answer I had posted?

Comment: @gurvinder372 I didn't see your answer but you have been faster 20 seconds.

Comment: no worries, hope that it solves OP's problem